# Why isn't scrapy finding anything on my local site?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a local site running at http://service.localhost:8021 and I am trying to scrape the image links (src attr) off the site. When I scrape it, it does seem to access it (as I get a 200 response); but no links returned.

My script is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
class crawlImages(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'crawlImages'
    allowed_domains = ["service.localhost"]
    start_urls = ['http://service.localhost:8021']
    def parse(self, response):

    titles = response.css('img::attr(alt)').extract()
    links = response.css('img::attr(src)').extract()
    print('##########')
    for item in zip(titles, links):
        all_items = {
            'title' : BeautifulSoup(item[0]).text,
            'link' :  item[1]
        }
        print(item[1])
        
        yield all_items
```

and I run it like this:

```
scrapy runspider crawlImages.py -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36" -s ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False
```

the response I get: deleted as not allowed to post it here.

Any hints?

Comment: does your response contains the links of all those images?

Comment: uh no, that would be silly wouldn't it. there are no links listed in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could print "titles" and "links" for debugging and your function indentation is incorrect.

Change

```
def parse(self, response):

titles = response.css('img::attr(alt)').extract()
links = response.css('img::attr(src)').extract()
print('##########')
for item in zip(titles, links):
    all_items = {
        'title' : BeautifulSoup(item[0]).text,
        'link' :  item[1]
    }
    print(item[1])
    
    yield all_items
```

To

```
def parse(self, response):
    titles = response.css('img::attr(alt)').extract()
    links = response.css('img::attr(src)').extract()
    print('##########')
    for item in zip(titles, links):
        all_items = {
            'title' : BeautifulSoup(item[0]).text,
            'link' :  item[1]
        }
        print(item[1])
        
        yield all_items
```

Check the response.body with:

```
print(response.body)
```

Try rewrite loop:

```
def parse(self, response):
    print(response.body)
    for img in response.xpath('//img'):
        title = img.xpath('./@alt').get()
        link = img.xpath('./@src').get()
        item = {}
        item['title'] = title
        item['link'] = link
        print(item)
        yield item
```

Comment: Didn't know Python was indent sensitive; but script runs so guessing i had it correct and just pasted wrong above. I pasted what you had and i get same result;this is a piece [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
[scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://service.localhost:8021> (referer: None)
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

Comment: What happens when you comment out "allowed_domains = ["service.localhost"]"?

Comment: I have tried commented out, [], [""] and a couple other things.. makes no difference.

Comment: Have you tried to comment out the whole line? Change `allowed_domains = ["service.localhost"]` to `#allowed_domains = ["service.localhost"]`

Comment: That's what i said above: "tried commented out". Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Please check the response.body by printing it and check out the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions; but i don't think this is targeting the correct issue. I did try what you posted above as "rewrite loop"; but these ideas are assuming something is scraped. I think from the output: [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) that the issue is related to allowed_domains or url or scrapy setup as it seems nothing is being scraped.

Comment: I tried a restart with this as a guide: https://shinesolutions.com/2018/09/13/running-a-web-crawler-in-a-docker-container/. It uses a scrapy command to  scaffold out a scraper. Once i had that set up it spit out the same result as above. Then i tried changing searching for A tags instead of IMG tags; and it did begin to scrape. So perhaps some issue with this. All my img src attrs are relative links; maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Perhaps this: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3755